# Azure Continuous WebJob "Graceful" Shutdown is less than 5 seconds

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have found this blog about WebJobs "Graceful" shutdown - http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VNZbLPmsXZ0

It says that Graceful Shutdown for Continuous WebJobs will by default be 5 seconds.

I want to send an email when my WebJob is shutting down so have tried the method detailed in the blog however this email does not send (I have an email that sends OK when the WebJob starts).

Looking at the logs of the webjob I think this might be because the shutdown is taking 1 second and not 5 seconds - if I am reading the logs correctly.

In the screenshot provided it appears that at 18:07:58 "WebJob is stopping" then at 18:07:58 "Status changed to Stopped", so not 5 seconds.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can ensure that the shut down period is 5 seconds?

Or even if it is possible to extend this shut down grace period to longer than 5 seconds for Continuous WebJobs?

Thanks in advance

** **Update** **

My issue was that I forgot that the FileWatcher event handler is on a different thread from the main thread. So the main thread was finishing, and the job stopping, before event handler logic had finished.
Have accepted Amit Apple's comment as this pointed me in the right direction.
Thanks to both of you for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebJobs runtime will wait 5 seconds by default before killing the process.
As I see from the logs, the process actually exited on it's own (probably since you've implemented the on shutdown detection) so there was no reason to wait and the shutdown process continued.

`"stopping_wait_time"` is the proper setting to use to extend the 5 seconds default.

Nice thing about open source, I can show you the code for this:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Core/Jobs/ContinuousJobRunner.cs#L156-L190

Answer (score 3):

From: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#continuous

> You can change the grace period of a job by specifying it (in seconds)
>   in the **settings.job** file (should be in the same root directory as the
>   job's script).
>
> ```
> { "stopping_wait_time": 60 }
> ```
>
> This will have the job grace period at 60 seconds instead of the default.

Also, be aware that if you have a webjob running you should set the Website to be "always on". This can be configured in the management portal.

Comment: I think the settings.job file is just for Triggered WebJobs and not Continuous WebJobs, unfortunately. I did try this anyway, just in case. My webjob is a console app and I added the file to the root directory with a setting of 60 seconds but this made no difference.

Comment: Also I think the option "always on" is only available for Standard Websites and not Free/Shared Websites. I am using Free Websites as I really don't won't to pay the significant expense for Shared Websites just to have one WebJob. Ideally I'd like the default 5 seconds to apply to my Continuous WebJob. http://blog.amitapple.com/post/73574681678/git-deploy-console-app/#.VNd7aPmsXZ1

Comment: Have you tried adding the file in the "properties" folder of the project?

Comment: I just tried this too, moving the settings.job file to the properties folder, but doesn't seem to affect the shutdown time period. Looking at the log for the job it still shows that the time between "SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down" and "SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped" is 1 second or less. Thanks for the tips though. Much appreciated.

Comment: @strangerinthealps actually it seems to work for continuous jobs as well for me